# Why is the pushforward of an invertible sheaf on BG to its coarse scheme not invertible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question really concerns a specific example. Let $G = \mu_2$ be the cyclic group of order 2. Let $* := \text{Spec }\mathbb{C}$, and let $BG := [*/\mu_2]$ the stack quotient, where $\mu_2$ acts trivially on $*$. Let $\mathcal{O}_{BG}$ denote the structure sheaf, and let $L$ denote the invertible sheaf on $BG$ corresponding to the nontrivial representation of $\mu_2$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Thus, $L(*\rightarrow BG) = \mathbb{C}$, and the action of $\mu_2$ on $*\rightarrow BG$ induces the inversion action of $\mu_2$ on $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $c : BG\rightarrow *$ denote the canonical map to its coarse scheme. I have heard that if $L$ denotes the invertible sheaf on $BG$ given by the nontrivial representation of $\mu_2$ on $\mathbb{C}$, then $c_*L$ is not invertible on $*$. However, following the definitions (see below), it seems that $c_*L$ is indeed invertible on $*$. Where have I gone wrong?

By the definition of pushforward, I believe the global sections of $c_*\mathcal{O}_{BG}$ should be equal to the limit
$$\lim\mathcal{O}_{BG}(*\rightarrow BG)$$
where the limit ranges over all morphisms $f : *\rightarrow BG$ satisfying $c\circ f = \text{id}_*$. Since the automorphism group of $*\rightarrow BG$ acts trivially on $\mathcal{O}_{BG}$, this is just the limit of the two-object diagram $\mathbb{C}\stackrel{\text{id}}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{C}$, which is just the diagonal in $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$.

Similarly, global sections of $c_*L$ should be the limit of the two object diagram $\mathbb{C}\stackrel{-1}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{C}$, which is just the set of pairs $\{(a,-a) : a\in\mathbb{C}\}$.

The action of $c_*\mathcal{O}_{BG}$ on $c_*L$ should be the coordinatewise multiplication action of the diagram $\mathbb{C}\stackrel{\text{id}}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{C}$ on the diagram $\mathbb{C}\stackrel{-1}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{C}$. Ie, on global sections, the action
$$c_*\mathcal{O}_{BG}\times c_*L\longrightarrow c_*L$$
should just be given by $((r,r),(a,-a)) \mapsto (ra,-ra)$. This seems to make $c_*L$ into an invertible sheaf on $*$, but I've heard that this is in fact not true. Where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pushforward $c_{\ast}L$ should be the limit of the diagram with one object "$\mathbb{C}$" and two (auto)morphisms "$\mathrm{id} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$" and "$-1 : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$"; in other words, it is the equalizer of $\mathrm{id}$ and multiplication-by-($-1$); thus in fact $c_{\ast}L = 0$.

A more general statement is: under the correspondence between quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{BG}$-modules and $G$-representations, the pushforward functor $c_{\ast}$ corresponds to the $G$-invariants functor.

If we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by a field of characteristic 2, then we'd have to be careful -- in general quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{B(\mathbb{Z}/(2))}$-modules are $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$-representations and quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{B\mu_{2}}$-modules are $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$-graded vector spaces (the pushforward here corresponds to taking the degree $0$ graded component).

Comment: to be clear, in your final paragraph, by $B(\mathbb{Z}/(2))$ you mean the classifying stack of the abstract cyclic group of order 2, whereas by $B(\mu_2)$ you mean the classifying stack of the group scheme $\mu_2$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. (We may also view $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ as a group scheme (over any field) in the obvious way.)